# Cursor does not go to top or bottom of window in Gvim 8

Tags: vim, scroll

Just re-imaged work machine (now with win 10) and reloaded Vim, now Gvim 8.  Just noticed this strange behavior in which cursor will *not* go to the very top or bottom of the page. It will only go as close as 6 lines from the top or bottom (unless at top or bottom of file). Doesn't seem to be scroll related, but more like a margin at top and bottom of page. Aside from that, all works fine but when I do H or L, I want to go all the way to top or bottom, not 6 lines away.

Also, regarding defaults.vim, it does not appear this was in my previous installation, but is now. But, doc says it is used if no `.vimrc` is found, but I have a `.vimrc`.

Comment: `:h 'scrolloff'` should explain this behaviour.

Comment: `Also, regarding defaults.vim ...` -- try `:scriptnames` to ensure your vimrc was loaded, and `:verbose set scrolloff?` to display which file set it.

Answer (score 18):

This is caused by the `scrolloff` option that is set to `5`by the new `defaults.vim`.

See `:help 'scrolloff'` and `:help defaults.vim`.